# Saving a Date in Excel from Datepicker

Tags: c#, excel, date, time, datepicker

I am trying to save a date from a DatePicker on a Windows Form, into an existing Excel 
Spreadsheet.

The following code assigns a string the ShortDate value of the DatePicker:

```
if (checkupCheck.Checked)
            {
                newCheckupDate = checkupPicker.Value.Date.ToShortDateString();
            }
            else
            {
                newCheckupDate = null;
            }
```

This value is then saved after being placed into a data grid with the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[i + 2, k + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[k].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
workbook.Save();
```

When looking at the value of the newCheckupDate string at a breakpoint, it appears as I would like it `"dd/mm/yyyy"`

When this is saved into Excel however, the cell will contain `"dd/mm/yyyy 00:00:00"`. I do not want the time being added. 
The cell is formatted as a date cell.

I have a feeling that Excel may be the cause of the problem here, but I don't know how to solve it.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without delving into the why, you can simply format the cell in the loop :

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, k + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[k].Value.ToString();
        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, k + 1].NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    }
}

workbook.Save();
```